# ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider on JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to implement Active Directory authentication with ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider on JBOSS EAP 6.3.

In case of user id to be authenticated is locked / expired I got following unexpected exception.

```
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException:
Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing;
nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException:
JBAS011843: Classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module
"deployment.multildap.war:main" from Service Module Loader
failed to instanciate InitialContextFactory 
com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory [Root exception is
javax.naming.AuthenticationException:
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9,
    comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 533, v1db1 ]]
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:217) [spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:187) [spring-security-ldap-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
...
```

My configuration is below and it works fine with Tomcat 8.

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="adAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="adAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="DOMAIN_NAME.COM" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://my-comain-controller/" />
</beans:bean>
```

I dived into ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider source code and the method bindAsUser has following section:

```
try {
    return contextFactory.createContext(env);
} catch (NamingException e) {
    if ((e instanceof AuthenticationException) || (e instanceof OperationNotSupportedException)) {
        handleBindException(bindPrincipal, e);
        throw badCredentials(e);
    } else {
        throw LdapUtils.convertLdapException(e);
    }
}
```

But in JBOSS it seems that raised NamingException is not an instance of AuthenticationException or OperationNotSupportedException. They are wrapped as root cause and the exception itself is an NamingException.

Quick and dirty solution may be adding some extra lines in the else section like below:

```
Throwable rootCause = e.getRootCause();
if ((rootCause instanceof AuthenticationException) || (rootCause instanceof OperationNotSupportedException)) {
    handleBindException(bindPrincipal, (NamingException) rootCause);
    throw badCredentials(rootCause);
} else {
    throw LdapUtils.convertLdapException(e);
}
```

Do someone has similer issue and/or have better solution?